# Windows NTLM authorization challenge expected

Tags: apache, http, jmeter

I have been trying to use NTLM authentication with jmeter but getting following 
"NTLM authorization challenge expected".

Also i am seeing NTLM response and NTLM Client Challenge empty on server response.

```
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.control.GenericController: Calling next on: org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: notifyFirstSampleAfterLoopRestart 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Start : sample htt p://ip.comain.com/csc/startup.do?subscriberid=101316984952&externalcaseid=51145083&xdgid=101316984952&user=101316984952@fiber&context=FTTb 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: method GET 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Created new HttpClient: @1552866196 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Found 0 cookies for htt p://ip.comain.com/csc/startup.do?subscriberid=101316984952&externalcaseid=51145083&xdgid=101316984952&user=101316984952@fiber&context=FTTb 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Target URL strings to match against: htt p://ip.domain.com/csc/startup.do?subscriberid=101316984952&externalcaseid=51145083&xdgid=101316984952&user=101316984952@fiber&context=FTTb and htt p://ip.domain.com:80/csc/startup.do 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Checking match against auth'n entry:  
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Matched 
2014/12/14 21:07:51 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: XXXX >  D=XXX D= R= 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Response headersSize=458 bodySize=415 Total=873 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Received Cookie: JSESSIONID=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499; path=/; HttpOnly From: htt p://ip.domain.com/csc/startup.do?subscriberid=101316984952&externalcaseid=51145083&xdgid=101316984952&user=101316984952@fiber&context=FTTb 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager: Add cookie to store ip.comain.com                TRUE                /              FALSE    0             JSESSIONID        9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Location set to - htt p://ip.domain.com/csc/spnego;jsessionid=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Start : sample htt p://ip.domain.com/csc/spnego;jsessionid=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: method GET 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Reusing the HttpClient: @1552866196 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Found 1 cookies for htt p://ip.domain.com/csc/spnego;jsessionid=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.HC3CookieHandler: Cookie: JSESSIONID=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Target URL strings to match against: htt p://ip.comain.com/csc/spnego;jsessionid=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 and htt p://ip.comain.com:80/csc/spnego;jsessionid=9QKpJNgDFLRd59GkZByHkvJhYSTcfGCHXCRTTNjpWQ1tmsQZc4FM!-1889773499 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Checking match against auth'n entry:  
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.control.AuthManager: Matched 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: EXT0191698 >  D=EXT0191698 D= R= 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 INFO  - org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor: ntlm authentication scheme selected 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 ERROR - org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector: ntlm authorization challenge expected, but not found org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthenticationException: ntlm authorization challenge expected, but not found
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor.processChallenge(AuthChallengeProcessor.java:159)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processWWWAuthChallenge(HttpMethodDirector.java:694)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.processAuthenticationResponse(HttpMethodDirector.java:668)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:193)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
                at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:269)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.followRedirects(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1411)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.resultProcessing(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1482)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.resultProcessing(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:306)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl.sample(HTTPHC3Impl.java:361)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1105)
                at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1094)
                at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:429)
                at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:257)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: Response headersSize=253 bodySize=0 Total=253 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: End : sample 
2014/12/14 21:07:52 DEBUG - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC3Impl: End : sample
```

Comment: Please use the edit link below your question and use its "code formatting" feature to clearly distinguish your machine code/text from your question text.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show Test Plan screenshot or describe how your [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) is configured and where it is placed in your Plan?

You can refer to [Windows Authentication with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/windows-authentication-apache-jmeter) guide for an example of configuring JMeter to work with NTLM authentication.